# How to Save Live (Real-Time) Data from One Tab to Another Using Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have live data importing from a web scraping service that imports everything to my google sheet. However, every time it scrapes a new set of data, it replaces the old data it scraped before. I would like to copy over all scraped data into a new tab to keep a record of everything. The code I'm currently using is not copying my existing data and when I test it by adding in a sample data set to be copied over, does not trigger. I understand I'll need to set up a trigger later to refresh any new data - any suggestions?

```
// custom menu function 
function onOpen() { 
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu') .addItem('Save Data','saveData') .addToUi(); 
} // function to save data 

function saveData() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet2'); 
  var state = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!A:A').getValue(); 
  var county = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!B:B').getValue(); 
  var apn = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!C:C').getValue(); 
  sheet.appendRow([state,county,apn]); 
}
```

Comment: The code above is what I am currently using

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function saveData() { 
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2'); 
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  var data=sh1.getRange(1,1,sh1.getLastRow(),3).getValues(); 
  sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

If you wish to change their position on the the output you can always use [.map array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).